if there are any recommended frontend open-source demos for microkernel architecture?
may I ask if there are any frontend recommended open-source demos?

It has the following UI architecture.
It uses a microkernel architecture.
We can write plugins to extend the software's functions (so can add content to the toolbar and plugin-bar inside).


